# How can I import python files correctly?

Tags: python, import, importerror

I have a folder that contains two other folders inside, like this:

```
training:
        |-- part1:
                 |-- __init__.py
                 |-- a.py

        |-- part2:
                 |-- __init.py
                 |-- b.py
```

when I want to import b.py in a.py, I get error. I've test two ways and get error in both of them explained here:

way1:

```
from training.part2.b import b
```

error:

```
Exception has occurred: ModuleNotFoundError
No module named 'training'
```

way2:

```
from ..part2.b import b
```

error:

```
Exception has occurred: ImportError
attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

can anyone help me to solve this problem? I will be very gratefull.

Comment: Put the module you are executing into the project root, then the root will become your import base.

Comment: how can i put it in project root

Comment: You know how to move files?

Comment: no, I want to import in this shape.

Comment: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/importing-files-from-different-folder) , try referencing the ans in  this link